# Unexpected unsymmetrical regular expression behavior of \< and \> in R

Tags: regex, r

Let me use the following example to illustrate.

```
str = "we are friends"
```

The help doc says that

> The symbols \< and \> match the empty string at the beginning and
>   end of a word.

So, the following is expected to happen, where a whitespace is added to the end of each word.

```
gsub("\\>"," ", str)
[1] "we  are  friends "
```

However, why it won't work when using

```
gsub("\\<"," ", str)
[1] " w e  a r e  f r i e n d s"
```

Can some explain why this happens? and what I need to do if I want an extra whitespace added in the front of every word?

Comment: Perhaps `gsub('\\b(?=\\w)', ' ', str, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Yet another comment rip-off, @akrun :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty strange but I think this is [documented as a warning](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

> POSIX 1003.2 mode of `gsub` and `gregexpr` does not work correctly with repeated word-boundaries (e.g., `pattern = "\b"`). Use `perl = TRUE` for such matches (but that may not work as expected with non-ASCII inputs, as the meaning of ‘word’ is system-dependent).

So, use `\\b(?=\\w)` or `(?<!\\w)\\b` with `perl=T`:

```
str = "we are friends"
gsub('(?<!\\w)\\b', ' ', str, perl=T)
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/vI3kFq)

Output: `[1] " we  are  friends"`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Could you please explain what (?<!\\w)\\b means? I know what \\w and \\b do, but it is still not clear to me why it works.

Comment: `(?<!\\w)` is a negative lookbehind that asserts that right before the word boundary `\\b` there is no alphanumeric character (a-zA-Z0-9_). These patterns do not consume text, they match empty space in other words, that is why you do not have to use capture groups with them.

Comment: As `\\b` matches between an alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters, and thus can match both at the beginning and end of words, the lookbehind just restricts it to match only the beginning of words.